# Return function with empty parameter or 1 parameter based on input paramer

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any cleaner code better than this?

Z is the function that can take either 1 parameter or an empty parameter. If I passed in y, then return z(y) else run z()

```
  async x (y?: string) {
    if(y) {
      return z(y)
    } else {
      return z()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why the intermediate? Just make the check in `z()` or add a default value `function z( x = "what ever default value you like" ) { ... }`

Comment: Why don't pass always `y` and check if is empty into function ?

Comment: ```return y?z(y):z()```

Comment: `return y ? z(y) : z();`

Answer (score 1):

```
  async x (y?: string) {
      return z(y || undefined);
  }
```

If you pass in `undefined` to a function, it's like you didnt pass in anything at all.

(I came up with this answer in the context of Javascript, not 100% sure that it's applicable exactly as is to typescript but I can't see why not)

Comment: shouldn't you use `??` instead of `||`. Since `0` is also a falsy value and it won't pass though...

Comment: @decpk I tried to mimic his original logic. He did `if (y) ...`

Comment: As per your logic `z(y || undefined)` is same as `z(y)`.

Comment: No, `z(y)` would pass in `z(0)` if `y == 0`, as you rightly pointed out. My code would do `z(undefined)` in that case. My code is not identical to `z(y)`, but my code is identical to the code he gave in his question

Comment: @decpk funnily enough, my answer here is functionally identical to the one you gave in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

```
async x(y) {
     return z( y ?? undefined)
}
```

This should do the work.

Comment: There are cases where this code doesn't behave exactly the same as his original code. `y = false` for example

Comment: we don't really know what `z(y)`  does -- maybe it treats `false`, `0`, and `undefined` the same, or maybe it doesn't. That's why it's worth considering.

Comment: The OP mentions that `y` would be a String. So I do believe that eliminates the possibility of `y = false or 0`.

Comment: `y = ''` in that case

Comment: In that case also, it means that `y = ''` has some value (which is anything apart from not even passing `y` in the first place), we would need to pass that to `z ( )`

Comment: In your example, you would pass it to `z()`, but in OPs original code, he would not. That's the difference I'm pointing out.

Comment: Well kinda strange on why wouldn't he? I think there is a gap somewhere in both of our understanding.